# Can I rotate already uploaded videos on YouTube?

Tags: youtube

Is it possible to rotate (90 degrees) already uploaded videos on YouTube?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

## There is no longer any way to rotate existing videos without re-uploading.

As of 22 August 2018, most of the video editing features were removed from YouTube. You are expected to use a separate video editing tool for most things.

If you have uploaded a video and afterwards decide you should have rotated it, you will need to use a video editor to rotate the original and re-upload. If you no longer have the original you can download the video from your YouTube account and follow the same edit/re-upload process.

You can view the [full post](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/youtube/TU6r2I0o1CI/dsLh7jY_DQAJ) from Jordan on the YouTube Help Forum, but here are the relevant details:

> **As of August 22, the following will no longer be available in Creator Studio Classic:**
>
> *Note: Any videos published with enhancements before August 22 will not be affected. Also, we’re not planning to bring the below classic
>   Enhancement features to YouTube Studio beta.*
>
> - Auto-fix
> - Stabilize
> - Fill Light
> - Contrast
> - Saturation
> - Color Temperature
> - Slow Motion
> - Timelapse
> - Filters
> - **Rotate**
>
> **Features that will still be available in Creator Studio Classic (and coming soon to YouTube Studio beta):**
>
> - Trim
> - Blur faces
> - Custom Blurring

Comment: Can you save changes back to the original video? or do you have to save the rotated video as a new video?

Comment: At this point you can make a copy of your video as one of the options...

Comment: It seems this option has been removed. I see only two options for Enhancements: Blur faces and Custom blurring.

Comment: The rotate feature was removed from YouTube's Creator Studio on August 22, 2018:
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/youtube/TU6r2I0o1CI/dsLh7jY_DQAJ

Comment: @user0 I would argue that this is still "the answer", as this answer has always operated under the assumption that people are looking to rotate their own uploaded videos so other people see it with the correct rotation, not that they want to rotate someone else's video so they can watch it. And judging by the number of votes it seems to be correct.

Comment: The second half is a direct quote from a Google employee on the YouTube help forum that backs up my statement that rotation is no longer available in their editor as it has recently been removed. It's part of writing a [good answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) and hardly spam-like and definitely not self promotion (or even promoting anything).

Comment: maybe it is possible to access the option, jan 2019 video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DFAuLyaPmxg

Answer (score 7):

Now you can rotate your video using the video enhancer: in [My videos](http://www.youtube.com/my_videos), select *Enhancements* from the menu below your video, then use the rotation icons.

Comment: Rotation no longer exists.

Answer (score 7):

Seeing how rotation has been stripped from Creator Classic, I thought this would be helpful here. I found a way to enable the native rotation buttons by modifying the element in Creator Classic.

Here are the steps:

1. Go to YouTube's Creator Classic
2. Go to Video Manager
3. Go to Enhancements
4. Right click on the "Trim" button and choose "Inspect"
5. A new window will popup highlighting the element you selected.  Just below the line that's selected, you'll see this tag with this element: hidden="true"
6. Double click to enter edit mode.
7. Simply delete hidden="true" and press enter.
8. Done!

The rotate buttons will appear and now you can use them as normal.  I suspect this will no longer be possible once YouTube completely switches over to the new Creator Studio in 2019, but...works for now!

If that explanation was not detailed enough, see it in action in my quick tutorial: https://youtu.be/OoBd0Qj6BKA

Comment: YouTube has officially retired Creator Classic, and as far as I can tell, this no longer works.

Answer (score 1):

## Yes, it's possible even without re-uploading the video:

- add this extension: **[https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rotate-that-video-player/ijpcmpbcokpgmecfkmehleemljfkeimo/related)**
- set the angles of rotation

[image]

Comment: I suppose this answer is valid if you assume the thought behind the question is "I found a video on YouTube and it's rotation is wrong; is there a way to rotate it so I can watch it in the correct orientation?" rather than "Can I change the rotation on a video I have already uploaded to YouTube so everyone sees it in the correct orientation?".

Comment: @Herohtar all I can read from OP question is: **Can I rotate already uploaded video's on YouTube? Is it possible to rotate (90 degrees) already uploaded video's on YouTube?** - there is nothing specific which explains if OP wants to rotate ***OPs' already uploaded videos*** or ***videos OP found uploaded on YT***

Comment: This really should be the answer to [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/66449/how-to-rotate-youtube-clips-during-playback), which recognizes this one as being about rotating your own uploaded videos.

Comment: But WHY would you rotate only for yourself and not for others?!! If a video is rotated wrong it's always wrong...! (Unless user has a really odd scenario which he then would have mentioned in a properly asked question as he would have realized people needed that piece of information to give a valuable answer.) So this answer makes no sense in real life.

Answer (score -1):

**you can use an extension for that:**

- install **[https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/turn-off-the-lights/bfbmjmiodbnnpllbbbfblcplfjjepjdn)**
- see demo **https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uj4aFy3YVhU**

**or you can use brute js force (works for any site):**

- press **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>** + **<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>** + **<kbd>C</kbd>**
- paste the following code, depending on your browser, into the javascript console
- **Chrome:**

`javascript: document.body.setAttribute( "style", "-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);");`

- **Firefox:**

`javascript: document.body.setAttribute( "style", "-moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);");`

- **Opera:**

`javascript: document.body.setAttribute( "style", "-o-transform: rotate(-90deg);");`

- press **<kbd>ENTER</kbd>**

Comment: You already have an answer on here suggesting an extension, why not just edit it and update with this info?