# How to rotate YouTube clips during playback

Tags: youtube

Unlike [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/11457/can-i-rotate-already-uploaded-videos-on-youtube), I would like to view someone else's clip that is already uploaded with wrong orientation (mostly because of holding the phone vertically).

I know this can be done by downloading the clip locally and watch it with VLC using it's rotation feature, but I find this procedure too cumbersome.

Is there an easy way to watch YouTube clips rotated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

YouTube doesn't offer this feature currently. However, VLC in the meantime added a feature allowing you to just stream YouTube videos simply by opening a network stream (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>) and pasting the YouTube URL there.

Comment: thanks. I wish google added this feature natively, but given that vlc works on all major os, and on phone/tablet you can simply rotate the phone then zoom in, I marked the answer as accepted.