# How to rotate multiple videos on YouTube?

Tags: youtube

I know how to rotate a YouTube video (enhancement, rotate, save) but is there a way to rotate multiple videos? I have hundreds of videos and I don't want to rotate them one by one. And I don't want to download them, rotate by myself and then re-upload. Any smart ways?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I rotate already uploaded video's on YouTube?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/11457/can-i-rotate-already-uploaded-videos-on-youtube)

Comment: I think the duplicate is more geared toward doing them one by one, which is not what the OP is after.

Comment: **Unfortunately, YouTube doesn't support multi-edit, so your only option is to do it 1-by-1.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### There is no way to rotate multiple videos in-place on YouTube.

In fact, it is no longer even possible to rotate *individual* videos in-place on YouTube, as they [removed most of the editing capabilities](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/youtube/TU6r2I0o1CI/dsLh7jY_DQAJ) on 22 August, 2018.

### Alternative

If you want to rotate all of your currently uploaded videos, you **will** have to download, edit, and re-upload them. (Unless you still have your originals, then you only have to edit and re-upload.)

Fortunately, with [Google Takeout](https://takeout.google.com/) you can download all of your YouTube videos at once, in their original quality. Once the videos are downloaded, the most efficient way to edit them would likely be to use a tool that supports batch editing or that can be called from a scripting language. I'm not well versed in video editing tools, but [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1245539/how-do-you-rotate-an-entire-directory-of-videos-with-ffmpeg) on Superuser or [this one](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/15390/best-way-to-batch-rotate-3000-h-264-videos) on Video Production SE could be a good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

### Unfortunately, YouTube doesn't support multi-edit, so your only option is to do it 1-by-1.

### _____________________________________________________________

### Alternatives:

**you can use an extension for that:**

- install **[https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/turn-off-the-lights/bfbmjmiodbnnpllbbbfblcplfjjepjdn)**
- see demo **https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uj4aFy3YVhU**

**or you can use brute js force (works for any site):**

- press **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>** + **<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>** + **<kbd>C</kbd>**
- paste the following code, depending on your browser, into the javascript console
- **Chrome:**

  `javascript: document.body.setAttribute( "style", "-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);");`
- **Firefox:**

  `javascript: document.body.setAttribute( "style", "-moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);");`
- **Opera:**

  `javascript: document.body.setAttribute( "style", "-o-transform: rotate(-90deg);");`
- press **<kbd>ENTER</kbd>**

### _____________________________________________________________

- add this extension: **[https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rotate-that-video-player/ijpcmpbcokpgmecfkmehleemljfkeimo/related)**
- set the angles of rotation

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Seeing how rotation has been stripped from Creator Classic, I thought this would be helpful here. I found a way by modifying the element in Creator Classic.
See my quick tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eDFNQiGZTKY.

I would have answered here ([Can I rotate already uploaded videos on YouTube?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/11457/can-i-rotate-already-uploaded-videos-on-youtube)), but it required much more rep than I have in order to comment.

Comment: Hi Drivium, I have removed the protection from that question for the time being.  It would be great if you could add the answer there, but please include a brief summary of what is going on in the video in the answer, otherwise if the video disappears the answer will not be able to stand on its own.  Please try to cater your answer to the individual questions rather than just copy/pasting what you have here, if you would, though.

Comment: Can you do it in a fast way without having to rotate one by one?

Comment: @jonsca - added detailed info at the link!  Thanks!  :)